# Why in many examples functions are called foo

Tags: coding-style

Maybe it's the wrong site, but I'm really curious why in so many examples in different languages they use **foo** as a name for functions or methods?

Comment: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69788/what-is-the-history-of-the-use-of-foo-and-bar-in-source-code-examples which links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163229/code-examples-foo-bar :)

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wiki page which explains a few possible reasons for it's history. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar#History_and_etymology

However The military term "FUBAR (F***ED up beyond all recognition/any repair/all reason)" but also some examples that show it's usage earlier as well.

Answer (score 2):

This probably comes from the FUBAR acronym, which stands for `F***ed Up Beyond All Repair`, and quickly got adapted into programming as `foobar`, and then `foo`, `bar` (and `baz` as an addition).

That is programming folklore really.

See Wikipedia on `FUBAR` for more historical trivia.

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica "FUBAR (F***ED up beyond all recognition/any repair/all reason)"